# PostgreSQL connection with PHP not working

Tags: php, linux, postgresql

I am trying to develop a basic page that uses PostgreSQL for the database.
The database is already set. Right now I was simply trying to create a connection with it.

```
<?php
    echo "test 1";
    $dbconn = pg_connect("host='localhost' port='5432' dbname='demorole' user='demorole' password='eta'") or die ("couldnt connect");
    echo "test 2";
?>
```

`demorole` is my database and its owner user. `eta` is a sample of password (but is correct)

My problem is that this page doesn't work at all. It doesn't display any errors. When i use the `function pg_connection_status()` it doesn't return anything. It only prints "test 1" (the `echo` commands are for debugging purposes).

I am working on Linux Mint.  Both PostgreSQL and Apache are running. The connection info are correct. Any idea what might be wrong? Because, since it doesn't display any errors, I'm stuck.

Comment: Does it work with MySQL?  edit:  What do the logs say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have `pgsql` php extension installed.

And turn on error displaying in php.ini

`display_errors = On
display_startup_errors = On`

Answer (score 0):

This code worked.

```
 $host        = "host=127.0.0.1";                         
 $port        = "port=5432";                        
 $dbname      = "dbname=mydb";                         
 $credentials = "user=myrole password=mypsw";

$connection = pg_connect( "$host $port $dbname $credentials"  );
if(!$connection){  echo "Error : Unable to open database\n"; } 
 return $connection;
```